# Datagridview.Rows(#).Selected not updating CurrentRow.Index

Tags: vb.net

VB.Net 4.6.1
Windows Forms application

I have a bound datagridview that I'm trying to sort and select. The data loads fine and I can click the headers (with some code) and the sorting works well. I'm working on reselecting a record after the sort is complete and I'm running into some trouble.

Assume that I have a datagridview with 20 records in it. On the form I also have a button that runs the following:

```
MessageBox.Show(MyDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index.ToString)
```

I also have a Sub that handles MyDataGridView.Sorted and in it I have one test line as follows:

```
MyDataGridView.Rows(2).Selected = True
```

After the data loads I click on the 11th record (selectionmode fullrowselect) and then I click the button. Box pops up and says "10" (0 based index). I click one of my column headers, the data sorts and the highlight bar jumps up to the 3rd record (index 2). However when I hit my currentrow.index button it still says 10. Additionally if I hit the down arrow key the selection bar jumps down to the 11th (index 10) record in the list.

It seems that using "Selected" doesn't update the currentrow.index value and since it is read-only I can't force it. Can anyone educate me on what's going on because, as it is, my users would be confused if the arrow up and down keys didn't work properly after a sort.

Thank you!

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you can set either `dgv.CurrentCell` or `dgv.CurrentCellAddress` to update the `dgv.CurrentRow.Index`.

Comment: Setting CurrentCell worked just fine. Thank you TnTinMn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Current" and "selected" do not mean the same thing.  How could they, when multiple rows can be selected but there can only be one current row?  The current row is the row that currently contains the caret and a selected row is one that is highlighted.  If you want the row at index 2 to be the current row then you need to make a cell in that row the current cell, i.e. assign a cell in that row to the `CurrentCell` property.

Comment: Setting CurrentCell worked just fine. Thank you jmcilhinney